# Nginx, Deluge, change port to default and use subdomain instead

Tags: nginx

I have this `example.com` domain.
I install Wordpress using Nginx, and it's all ok in `example.com`.
I install Deluge, Deluge WebUI, default port is 8112, and `example.com:8112` is all ok again also for Deluge Web UI.
I didn't install anything for Python in Nginx for Deluge, Deluge has it's own web server (I think).
However **I want to be able to use Deluge WebUI from `subdomain.example.com`, instead of (`example.com:8112` or `subdomain.example.com:8112`).**
I don't care much if the other solution will keep working as well, I would prefear not to, but what is really important for me is to deliver a working Deluge Web UI at `subdomain.example.com`
By default, even with Nginx stopped, both `subdomain.example.com:8112` and `example.com:8112` work and redirect me to Deluge WebUI properly.
However I'm unable to proxy Nginx with default ports (80/443) to Deluge listening in 8112.
I tried many solutions with Nginx, I even managed to redirect to the Deluge Web page, but all I see is a blank page (though inspecting it with dev tool I see that there is the deluge code behind it, and the url inside, like /somewhere/something.css are working as well).
It is not even a problem of permission, because (after making a backup copy to restore them properly) I even tried to give 777 with -R in the deluge web directory.
The blank page as before actually has some javascript errors, it's likely that that is blocking, but they work on the port 8112, so maybe is some javascript not redirecting to the correct port?
That's one of the Nginx configuration I tried. I tried many, I can't list all the possibilities I tried.
`server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        ## redirect http to https ##
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
        listen  443;
        server_name subdomain.example.com;
        root /usr/share/pyshared/deluge/ui/web;
        index index.html;
        location / {
                proxy_pass httTHIS IS INSIDE A CODE WTH ps://localhost:8112;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
                proxy_pass_header P3P;
        }
        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }
        location ~* .(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.example.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.example.com.error.log;
}`

**bold** is where I edited server specific informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems i have been able to make it works, following these steps :

Install packages : `deluge` `deluge-webui` `deluged`

Then start `deluge-web` :

`# deluge-web` or `# deluge-web --fork` to have it running in background

Then setup `NGinx` like this :

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name subdomain.example.com;

  location / {
     proxy_pass http://192.168.0.47:8112; # IP Address of your Server 
  }
}
```

---

For https (port 443), first i've setup `deluge` to use https :

- I've create a self-signed certificate [following instructions
  here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04) (step One to Four)
- Then, [following this](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq#HowdoIusehttps), i've copied `server.crt` and `server.key`
  in `$HOME/.config/deluge/ssl`
- Open `$HOME/.config/web.conf` and setup like this :

  ```
  "pkey": "ssl/server.key",
  "cert": "ssl/server.crt",
  "https": true,
  ```
- Then restart `deluge-web`
- Finally setup `NGinx` :

  ```
  server {
     listen       443;
     server_name subdomain.example.com;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

     location / {
       proxy_pass https://192.168.0.47:8112; # IP Address of your Server
     }
  }
  ```

---

Note that it seems you cannot use `deluge` with both `http` and `https` : you have to choose one or another.

Comment: There is no need to have deluge work via https. Nginx could connect to deluge via http protocol while client connect to nginx via https.

Comment: @alexeyten Never break the SSL chain ! Here, Nginx and deluge are on the same server, so a man in the middle is difficult. However never do this when your frontend server is not the same as the backend server. So, more generally, keep SSL all over the way, or don't use SSL at all.

Comment: I wouldn't be so categorical. If one could listen to traffic inside your server, is doesn't matter if it is encrypted or not, so it's just a waste of resources and time.