# Setup nginx ssl reverse proxy subdomain for Deluge

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, subdomain

Yes another nginx reverse proxy question, but [deluge documentation](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/WebUI/ReverseProxy) seems unhelpful and the only [relevant post](https://serverfault.com/questions/583985/nginx-deluge-change-port-to-default-and-use-subdomain-instead) I found was not solving my problem.

I have a working Deluge web UI running at https://example.org:8112.

I already created a A DNS record deluge.example.org to my_ip.

So I wanted to setup a nginx reverse proxy in order to use the subdomain with deluge.

Server OS : ArchLinux

So here what I tried:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # Redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS with a 301 Moved Permanently response.
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name deluge.example.org;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/deluge.cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/deluge.key.pem;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Using list of ciphers from "Bulletproof SSL and TLS"
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA";

    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.org:8112/;
        # proxy_set_header X-Deluge-Base "/deluge/";
    }
}
```

Note: I made a symbolic link from `/srv/deluge/.config/deluge/ssl/deluge.cert.pem` to `/etc/nginx/ssl/deluge.cert.pem` and same think for teh key.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen exactly and what happens instead? What do log files tell?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I expected that when accessing https://deluge.example.org I would have accessed the same service as for https://example.org:8112. Instead of that I get `The connection failed - Connexion refused`. Logs files don't say anything because there is no error, the configuration is good but just doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Are you sure your nginx is running?

Comment: @Nero, sure, I restarted it several times and checked the status each time